# Scheduling Autosys jobs once in two months

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys

How can the `autosys` jobs be scheduled to run on 1st day of every other month?

I tried setting condition `MNTHD#1`, but it runs on every month.

Answer (score 0):

I would use extended calendar to accomplish this.